# bootstrap linked datetime picker not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui

hi i am trying to develop bootstrap jquery for linked datetime  pickers but is not working correctly am using jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/srknthcse/CujDK/311/ i have selected No-library ...any help will be appreciated .thank you

```
<div class="container">
    <div class='col-md-5'>
       <div class="form-group">
<div id="startdatetime-from" class="input-append date">
    <input type="text" id="datetimepicker-input" readonly ></input>
    <span class="add-on">
        <i data-time-icon="icon-time" data-date-icon="icon-calendar"></i>
    </span>
    <div class='col-md-5'>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div id="startdatetime-from1" class="input-append date1">
    <input type="text" id="datetimepicker-input1" readonly ></input>
    <span class="add-on">
        <i data-time-icon="icon-time" data-date-icon="icon-calendar"></i>
    </span>
</div>
</div>
```

```js
var d = new Date();
var month = d.getMonth();
var day = d.getDate();
var year = d.getFullYear();
var hours= d.getHours();
var minutes=d.getMinutes();
$(function() {
$('#startdatetime-from').datetimepicker({
    language: 'en', 
    showMeridian:'true',
    autoclose:'true',
    format: 'hh:mm PP dd-MM-yyyy '
});
$("#startdatetime-from").data('datetimepicker').setLocalDate(new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes));

var d1=new Date();
var d2=new Date(d1);
var addedhour=d2.setHours(d1.getHours()+4);
$('#startdatetime-from1').datetimepicker({
    language: 'en',
      showMeridian:'true',
    autoclose:'true',
    format: 'hh:mm dd-MM-yyyy '
});
$("#startdatetime-from1").data('datetimepicker').setLocalDate(new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes));
$("#startdatetime-from").on("dp.change", function (e) {
            $('#startdatetime-from1').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(e.date);
        });
        $("#startdatetime-from1").on("dp.change", function (e) {
            $('#startdatetime-from').data("DateTimePicker").maxDate(e.date);
        });


});
```

Comment: not working properly? what is happening?

Comment: Only problem I noticed was when I was clicking on the second date picker first was also opening. I have corrected it in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SukanyaHalder/CujDK/313/). If there is any other issue then tell me.

Comment: Hi am facing these problems 1)In first  datepicker i need to display date& time by default and calender icon should be disable .2) In second datepicker i need to display date& time and  i want to add 4 hours to current time . i.e., in first picker 12-08-2015 11:30PM for that in second date picker 13-08-2015 3:30AM  i have  code but it is not working as expected  jsfiddle link  http://jsfiddle.net/srknthcse/CujDK/318/  any help please thank you

Comment: my source for that is http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/ but i need to add my own feature  like second date picker  should display 4 hours more than first and in first date picker calender icon only disable

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="container">
    <div class='col-md-10'>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div id="startdatetime-from" class="input-append date">
                <input type="text" id="datetimepicker-input"  readonly></input> 
        </div>
       <div></div>
            <div class='col-md-10'>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div id="startdatetime-from1" class="input-append date1">
                        <input type="text" id="datetimepicker-input1"  readonly></input> 
                        <span class="add-on">
                        <i data-time-icon="icon-time" data-date-icon="icon-calendar"></i>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


var d = new Date();
var month = d.getMonth();
var day = d.getDate();
var year = d.getFullYear();
var hours = d.getHours();
var minutes = d.getMinutes();
$(function () {
    $('#startdatetime-from').datetimepicker({
        language: 'en',
        autoclose: 'true',
        format: 'HH:mm PP dd-MM-yyyy '
    });
    $("#startdatetime-from").data('datetimepicker').setLocalDate(new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes));

    $('#startdatetime-from1').datetimepicker({
        language: 'en',
         autoclose: 'true',
        format: 'HH:mm PP dd-MM-yyyy '
    });

    $("#startdatetime-from1").data('datetimepicker').setLocalDate(new Date(year, month, day, hours+4, minutes));
});
```